# SVG as Xamarin.Forms Button image

Tags: xaml, button, svg, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms Shared project and I'm working on UI (XAML). I want to use SVG image as a button image in my app. The problem is that I don't know how to do that.
I will be grateful if someone  will show me how to do that step by step.

Comment: Sorry, I voted to close, please refer to the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to find out what is wrong. Please at the least list what you have tried so far and where you have failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert SVG to XAML using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

1. Open the SVG
2. Save As...   Microsoft XAML
3. Use the XAML in your button style

Comment: Would you mind explaining more? How can it be used the XAML in the button style?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore. The Xaml produced is not compatible with xamarin. Try something like https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/

Answer (score 2):

First convert svg file to android vector using the [this link](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/). Then add an android vector file (xml) like below:

[image: Where to add xml file]

And finally use this file as button Image

```
<Button Image="vector.xml">
```

Comment: What about IOS vector?